# Where to manage a general void method that is used in most of my controller action methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following method, which accept an array of ids and populate a view Data parameters, as follow:-

```
 private void populateViewData(long[] it360ids)
        {
            var resources = repository.GetResources(it360ids);
            foreach (var resource in resources)
            {
                string c = resource.RESOURCENAME;
                long id = resource.RESOURCEID;

                ViewData["NAME" + resource.RESOURCEID.ToString()] = resource.RESOURCENAME;
                ViewData["CustomerNAME" + resource.RESOURCEID.ToString()] = resource.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.AccountDefinition.ORG_NAME;

        }
```

I have this method used in most controller classes, and currently I am adding this method at the end of each controller class. But my question is about how I can define this method in one place and refer to it from my associated action methods?
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can create your own ControllerBase :

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    protected void populateViewData(long[] it360ids) { ... }
}
```

After, you have to use `MyController` in all existing Controller with :

```
public class HomeController : MyController { ... }
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: method code can be pull into constructor.. what the use of private void method..in this scenario..

Answer (score 0):

Base class is a great option, another way to do this would be via **Dependency Injection**.

**Create an interface**

```
public interface IViewDataPopulator
{
    void populateViewData(long[] it360ids,ViewDataDictionary ViewData);
}
```

**Create at least one implementation**

```
public class BasicViewDataPopulator:IViewDataPopulator
{
  public void populateViewData(long[] it360ids,ViewDataDictionary ViewData)
  { 
     //code goes here
  }
}
```

**Declare the depdendency on the controller constructor**

```
public class MyController
{
   readonly IViewDataPopulator _populator;
   public MyController(IViewDataPopulator populator)
   {
      if (populator==null) throw new ArgumentNullException("populator"); //etc, etc
      //store it...
      _populator=populator;
   }
}
```

**Wire it up**

Setup an IoC framework (Ninject, Unity, etc) in your MVC project to handle the actual injections whereby for a given interface (`IViewDataPopulator`) request it will hand out a given implementation (e.g. `BasicViewDataPopulator`)

- An advantage of this method is, because you are injecting by interface, you can easily handle the cases where certain controllers might need a slightly different function - in this case you just create a new implementation (say, `SpecialCaseViewDataPopulator`) and modify your DI setup to hand out instances of that class when requested for specific controllers, etc.

**Finally!**

Now all of your controller's Action methods can use `_populator.populateViewData` any time they like, without having to know anything about if it's a `BasicViewDataPopulator`,`SpecialCaseViewDataPopulator`, etc.